# What does it mean to create predictions on predicted probabilities?

Tags: probability, predictive-models, ecology, probabilistic-programming

**Background:**
I have a particular dataset of presence and absence of a specific bird. This data went through various means of simplification for machine learning techniques, for example random forests and a calibration model to finally predict the probability of encounter given a collection of X variables onto a raster, to map out these encounters. This was implemented over several years of MODIS landcover data, and finally I managed to gather the changes in landcover (Covariates - X variables), from year-to-year relative to independent habitat types.

The dataset looks like this:

```
#glimpse
encounter  year landcover pland_change ly_name         
      <dbl> <dbl> <chr>            <dbl> <chr>           
1    0.0303  2011 barren         -0.143  Prairie_Potholes
2    0.0327  2011 barren         -0.143  Prairie_Potholes
3    0.0280  2011 barren         -0.143  Prairie_Potholes
4    0.0243  2011 barren         -0.0556 Prairie_Potholes
5    0.0627  2011 barren         -0.0833 Prairie_Potholes
6    0.0201  2011 barren         -0.100  Prairie_Potholes
```

Variables:
**Encounter** - This was calculated using randomforest on presence/absence data, to estimate the probability of encounter. The finaly calculation has actually gone through a calibration and prediction model to get the final values of `encounter`.
**pland_change** - These are the differences in pland relative to `landcover`, where `ly_name` represents the BCR region in which they're from. `pland_change` was calculated from MODIS MCD12Q1 yearly landcover data. The calculation of pland was performed with the following calculation:
$$Pland = P_I =\frac{\sum_{j=1}^{n}a_{ij}}{A}(100)$$

PLAND is equal to the sum of areas ($m^2$) of all patches corresponding the patch type ($a_{ij}$), divided by the total landscape area ($m^2$), and multiplied by 100 (to convert into percentages).

So **pland_change** is the difference of every year after 2010 (2010-2019), minus from 2010, to calculate the difference of pland from 2010.

A simple introduction into my processing is taken from [here](http://PLAND%20is%20equal%20to%20the%20sum%20of%20areas%20(%7B557bfc32-0719-4632-a6ef-a5e4ba2a0ca3%7D)%20of%20all%20patches%20corresponding%20the%20patch%20type%20(%7B0007e88b-8b77-4dc4-a9ee-a06f005b846e%7D),%20divided%20by%20the%20total%20landscape%20area%20(%7Bdaf23e6c-6b47-4344-8ba0-ec10f6cc6209%7D),%20and%20multiplied%20by%20100%20(to%20convert%20into%20percentages).) (3 and 4)

Research goal:
My dataset above, after following the procedures from the link. I extracted those value from a `raster` with habitat and encounter values, then coerced them into a single dataframe. Given the following steps provided, I had the thought of proceeding with the information below if possible.

**Question:**
What does it mean to create predictions of estimated encounter-probabilities on relative habitat changes? Given that the estimated encounter-probabilities are predictions based on species presence – absence data, altogether, they’re likelihood estimations with a given error, of encountering a presence of species. Although, to predict the likelihood presence, as a further prediction of landcover changes, what does it mean to predict, a predicted probability of encounter given that these predictions were calculated on independent habitat types, and now they're predicted relative to habitat changes from year-to-year?

**Summary:** Can you predict a predicted probability of encountering a bird?

Comment: Can one predict the chance of rain today? ;-)

Comment: Could you explain the data and research goals better?

Comment: @whuber Would this have the same inductive meaning today, relative to 100 years ago?

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen I'll be glad to provide further explanations, although, is there anything specific that you require me to explain in more detail? I can provide a precise account of my methodology, although it may exceed 1000 word count? Although, I can point my methodlogy to an article that explains it similarly (simplistically), whilst providing a detailed account on 'research goals'.

Comment: At least explain your variables, what is `encounter`, `pland_change`? I hope I have understood the others ... are those vars model output? A link is fine, but a short abbrev description in the Q text will be better (in addition to the link)

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen I have updated my post, please let me if more detail is required as i'll be glad to provide more if necessary.